# why top level folder is not a package

Tags: python-2.7, package

Have a structure like this:

```
  test
    |
    |------- __init__.py
    |
    |------- Modules/(package)
    |           |
    |           |----- __init__.py
    |           |----- LDAPManager.py
    |           |----- PasswordManager.py
                |----- other_scripts/  (package)
                              |------module1.py
                              |------__init__.py
    |
    |------- Scripts/(package)
    |           |
    |           |----- __init__.py
    |           |----- CreateUser.py
    |           |----- FindUser.py
```

In module1, I want to import a function from FindUser, so I use:
from test.Scripts.FindUser import func1
then I see this error:
ImportError: No module named test.Scripts.FindUser

It seems this error is because test is not recognized as package, but why?
Or another reason causes to fail?

Comment: Is the folder above `test` in `sys.path`? Is this directory structure you've shown installed somewhere, or are you running a program from somewhere within it?

Comment: The folder above test is not in sys.path, I tried to add it to sys.path and it works. I am running a program within it.